# MySql pivot table for scatter chart

Tags: mysql, pivot

I would like to transform the following sql (e.g. `select Name,X,Y from mytable`) result:

```
Name  | X   | Y
bla1  | 0.1 | 0.2
bla2  | 0.3 | 0.4
```

Into the following form that is displayed correctly in an Excel scatter chart (i.e. with each row as a series and each name as a label):

```
Name  | 0.1 | 0.3
bla1  | 0.2 | 
bla2  |     | 0.4
```

This is the only way a scatter chart will display x-y data correctly without fiddling with chart settings:
[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I figured this out with help from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value).

```
    SELECT CONCAT(
      'SELECT `mytable`.Name', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
         ,    `t_', REPLACE(Y, '`', '``'), '`.X
             AS `', REPLACE(Y, '`', '``'), '`'
       ) SEPARATOR ''),
     ' FROM `mytable` ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
         LEFT JOIN `mytable`   AS `t_', REPLACE(Y, '`', '``'), '`
                ON `mytable`.Name = `t_', REPLACE(Y, '`', '``'), '`.Name
               AND `t_', REPLACE(Recall, '`', '``'), '`.Y= ', QUOTE(Recall)
       ) SEPARATOR ''),
     ' GROUP BY `mytable`.Name'
    ) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT Recall FROM `mytable` WHERE ... ) t;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

Initially this was not working because the datatype of columns `X` and `Y` was `FLOAT` which I suspect was messing up the conversion to string. I changed the type to be `DECIMAL(10,9)` (i.e. a single digit, followed by up to nine decimal points), which made the code work.

Comment: This still doesn't work in my confluence page actually. It only works in the MySQL command-line. I suspect it's a quoting issue but don't understand enough about the code to be able to debug it. Help?